# I recently create a project of OPNET 14.5 and i have been unable to run the simulation. the error is about Pipeline stage model (dpt_ecc_pon)

Tags: opnet

I installed OPNET modeler 14.5 at my laptop (OS: Windows 8).

I slightly modified a process model, and ran simulation. But I see the following errors.

```
<<< Recoverable Error >>>
Pipeline stage model (dpt_ecc_pon) compilation failed
Source code was unavailable to the compiler

----

<<< Recoverable Error >>>
Object repository construction failed
Pipeline stage (dpt_ecc_pon) compilation failed, no source code found.
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE)

----

<<< Program Abort >>>
Error encountered rebuilding repository -- unable to proceed
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE)
```

How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create `dpt_ecc_pon` pipeline stage source, there are some rules to define them. Based on your error message, the `dpt_ecc_pon.ps.c/cpp` is not included in the `model_dirs`.

All source code should be included in `model_dirs`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. In preference dialog, search 'model_dirs' and make sure the directory where your codes are included in the 'model_dirs'.